# How to dynamically update property in one ViewModel based on settings set in other ViewModels?

Tags: c#, android, forms, xamarin

I have this in my ViewModel #1

```
public bool IsThereAProperty
{
    get
    {
        return App.Current.Properties.ContainsKey("myKey");
    }
}
```

I bind from this property in my view. 
How can I update this, so that if I add a key to App.Current.Properties (in other ViewModels) the changes will be respected in this ViewModel #1 and my view as well ?

Comment: How did you asign your App.Current.Properties? Is it a static array or what?

Comment: Based on a clicked switch element in other view. It's a flag - true or false. App.Current is a static and Properties are IDictionary. This is from xamarin. For reference - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.application.properties?view=xamarin-forms

Comment: you have both viewmodels existing at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the property in the ViewModel will not update dynamically,through the `App.Current.Properties` is the global property,if you add a key to `App.Current.Properties` in other ViewModels,the global property will change,but your `IsThereAProperty` property in your ViewModel will not,because it's just the property of your viewmodel,so you should notify your viewmodel to update the `IsThereAProperty`,then the view which binding it will update.

You could use [MessagingCenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center) to notify the viewmodel when you add a key in another viewmodel.

e.g. in viewmodel#2 you add a key and remove the key:

```
if (!App.Current.Properties.ContainsKey("myKey"))
  {
    App.Current.Properties.Add("myKey", true);
    MessagingCenter.Send<string, bool>("change", "add a key", App.Current.Properties.ContainsKey("myKey"));

  }
else
  {
    App.Current.Properties.Remove("myKey");
    MessagingCenter.Send<string, bool>("change", "add a key", App.Current.Properties.ContainsKey("myKey"));
  }
```

then in you viewmodel#1:

```
public class Model1 : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public bool isIsThereAProperty;
    public bool IsIsThereAProperty
    {
        set
        {

           isIsThereAProperty = App.Current.Properties.ContainsKey("myKey");
           OnPropertyChanged("IsIsThereAProperty");

        }
        get
        {
            return App.Current.Properties.ContainsKey("myKey");
        }
    }

    public Model1()
    {
        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<string>("change","add a key" ,(sender)=>
        {

            OnPropertyChanged("IsIsThereAProperty");

        });
    }
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```